# Is there a specific reason why Justice League ended on Batman?

Tags: dc, batman, dc-animated-universe, justice-league-unlimited

In the end of *Justice League Unlimited* animated TV series, all of heroes were displayed running towards us (viewers) and disappeared one by one out of view. The last one was Batman. The screen went black forever on Bats’ symbol on his chest.

I wonder why Superman (leader of JL and most focused-on character in the show) wasn’t the last one. He was the second last. Is there a specific reason why Batman was the last one?

Comment: Superman is only the moral leader of the Justice League, the actual leadership fell to the Martian Manhunter, Mister Terrific, and Batman. Also, he's the goddamn Batman. Also, the slowest of the final three ;P

Answer (score 14):

Batman was the first to debut in the [DCAU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_animated_universe) having made his first appearance in the premiere episode of [Batman the Animated Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_the_animated_series) in 1992.  It seems only fitting that they close JLU and the Animated Universe out with him as well.

[image]

Comment: It's worthwhile to note that the penultimate season finale of JLU featured an homage to the first scene of Batman:TAS, for the same reason (they didn't know at the time they would get another season, so they made it like it was the final episode).

Comment: Also Superman doesn't have a black bat on his chest, so if you zoom in on his chest you don't get the smooth cut to black.